# Doing a calculation in a while loop

Tags: php

I have the following variables inside a WHILE loop:

```
    $row['To'];
    $row['From'];
```

Those represent a time, example:

```
$row['To'] ="10:00:00";
 $row['From'] = "08:00:00";
```

In a normal calculation I will do the following to get the hours in difference:

```
 $result = (strtotime($row['To']) - strtotime($row['From']));
   $hours      = floor($result / 60 / 60);
   $minutes    = round(($result - ($hours * 60 * 60)) / 60);
```

The problem is that now I have to do in a while loop, where $row['to'] and $row['From'] must be calculated all the times the loop dictate...But I cannot get it work. This is what I tried:

```
function calculateHours($project, $worker, $year, $month) {
if($project) {
$q='SELECT * FROM project_timeline WHERE ID="'.$project.'" AND Year(Date) = "'.$year.'" AND Month(Date) = "'.$month.'" AND WorkerID="'.$worker.'"';
 }else{
$q='SELECT * FROM project_timeline WHERE Year(Date) = "'.$year.'" AND Month(Date) = "'.$month.'" AND WorkerID="'.$worker.'"';
 }
 $r=mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error());   
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    $result .= (strtotime($row['To']) - strtotime($row['From']));
   }
    $hours      = floor($result / 60 / 60);
    $minutes    = round(($result - ($hours * 60 * 60)) / 60);
 return $hours.' hour(s) and '.$minutes.' minutes';
}
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `.=` for calculating numbers ( time ) in PHP this is string addition , for adding numbers use `+=`.

And just for clever code - put `$result = 0;` in the beginning of the function

PS. Also instead of floor, try to use `%` -

```
$result     = round($result / 60);
$minutes    = $result % 60;
$hours      = ( $result - $minutes ) / 60;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `return` like that inside your `while()` loop is going to terminate the loop on the first iteration and only ever produce results for the FIRST row of data you've fetched from the database.

Comment: Ah figures... bad indentation strikes again.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class for this:

```
// other function code here...

$from = new DateTime($row['From']);
$to   = new DateTime($row['To']);
$diff = $from->diff($to);

return $diff->format('%h hour(s) and %i minutes');
```

Comment: @SergeS: I misunderstood what he was trying to do.  `DateInterval` will not work for this, because you can't specify total denomination and get hours/minutes/seconds (it would be a nice addition for a future PHP version, though!).

Comment: You can always do this trick - take first From To, and any next differenc add to first TO time ( so first From-To will make computed difference )

Comment: @SergeS: That is a nice trick!  I never thought about that.  Thank you.  :-)